# puppet device fails in the middle of finding facts

Tags: cisco, puppet

I'm in the process of trying to get the 'puppet device' functionality working for configuring cisco switches. What I'm running into is I have a cisco 2960 in the master with a signed certificate. The device is in site.pp and devices.conf. I'm calling puppet device with the correct puppetmaster as --server. I can see in the router history that it is actually connecting and running the first two commands, however puppet comes back and states "Error: Could not retrieve local factsL: connection closed by remote host." I can find absolutely nothing in the switch config that would cause this either, it's basically unconfigured except for SSH and an enable password. I've confirmed all the relevant hostnames resolve properly and the passwords are good.

I've also gone into puppet/utils/network_devices/transport/ssh.rb and forced the ssh output to print with prettyprint (because it doesn't seem to respect --verbose despite the code being in there) and it kicks out the ouptut from the first 4 lines puppet runs (terminal length 0, enable, sh vlan brief, sh ver) and I can also edit facts.rb to kick out the 'facts' variable and it does have data in it.

Relevant files included below:

puppet --version: 3.1.1
net-ssh version: 2.6.7

Commandline: `puppet device --debug --verbose --server puppet.internal.domain`

Relevent output:

```
Debug: Finishing transaction 70266566593300
Debug: command
Debug: connecting to switchname.internal.domain as puppet
Error: Could not retrieve local facts: connection closed by remote host
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not retrieve local facts: connection closed by remote host
Debug: Value of 'preferred_serialization_format' (pson) is invalid for report, using default (b64_zlib_yaml)
Debug: report supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml raw yaml; using b64_zlib_yaml
```

puppet.conf

```
devicedir = /bollocks #(yeah the rhel 6 packages from puppetlabs are broken, had to move this due to permission issues)
color = none

[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl

[agent]
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

device.conf

```
[switch.internal.domain]
type cisco
url ssh://puppet:puppet@switch.internal.domain/?enable=password
```

site.pp #this has yet to actually apply but it's here for completeness

```
node "switch.internal.domain" {
               interface {"GigabitEthernet0/2":
                              description => "Hello World",
               }
}
```

switch configuration:

```
!
version 15.0
no service pad
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
service password-encryption
!
hostname infra-sw06
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 4 LcV6aBcc/53FoCJjXQMd7rBUDEpeevrK8V5jQVoJEhU #password
!
username puppet privilege 15 password 7 055E2A1C0B54471C3E #puppet
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login CONSOLE line
aaa authentication enable default enable
!
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
system mtu routing 1500
!
!
ip domain-name switch.internal.domain
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-713306880
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-713306880
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-713306880
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-713306880
 certificate self-signed 01
  30820229 30820192 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 05050030
  30312E30 2C060355 04031325 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274
  69666963 6174652D 37313333 30363838 30301E17 0D393330 33303130 30303231
  365A170D 32303031 30313030 30303030 5A303031 2E302C06 03550403 1325494F
  532D5365 6C662D53 69676E65 642D4365 72746966 69636174 652D3731 33333036
  38383030 819F300D 06092A86 4886F70D 01010105 0003818D 00308189 02818100
  BBC9A195 E8B6B18B 14F3A70C 54AF3D0F 813DA933 044C4364 B7C975A1 B29E6F4A
  871D06AD D7CC8FBF 053EF3B2 BADE30B9 CE31BE4B C9906025 2AEA1930 12BD63E0
  3569BBBB 705105E9 7897BE1B EFE96F37 FAD909BC 46100E35 C6EFC1A6 31A072CC
  20857391 76A2A387 40ACFEF6 DE756394 603C47FE 14EC5A3F 21EB17FD 9434A129
  02030100 01A35330 51300F06 03551D13 0101FF04 05300301 01FF301F 0603551D
  23041830 16801411 E123DCC7 610C0B59 ED6C8C4A ED3BA025 4B5E6930 1D060355
  1D0E0416 041411E1 23DCC761 0C0B59ED 6C8C4AED 3BA0254B 5E69300D 06092A86
  4886F70D 01010505 00038181 00611012 EC921E96 182CCE34 7500BA85 887C8F15
  83C17157 680B4F09 217B974E 78437407 D30D20A6 CC962DB6 B7164F12 56A0897D
  04511E89 71BC3D8B ED50588B 364FF062 55D3D8A7 5F41541C B55488A3 91262714
  185069BF C355D263 A359BF71 0B4E571C CC7A7BFD B8BACAC3 5CF4AB81 05D02EE2
  D9E49A95 89A71B95 C34ECBBE 57
        quit
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
!
!
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/25
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/26
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/27
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/28
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/29
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/30
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/31
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/32
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/33
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/34
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/35
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/36
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/37
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/38
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/39
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/40
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/41
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/42
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/43
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/44
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/46
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/47
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/48
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address <scrubbed> 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway <scrubbed>
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
line con 0
     password 7 <scrubbed>
 login authentication CONSOLE
line vty 0 4
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 transport input ssh
!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have it!!! Try downgrading your net-ssh gem. From what I have read newer version includes more exceptions that are not catered for in puppet code. For puppet 3.2 I reverted back to net-ssh (2.1.4) and it seems to have fixed the problem.